# Slick 3.1 - SELECT statements have a different number of columns error for play 2.5.x

Tags: mysql, scala, playframework, slick

We recently migrated our play application from 2.4.x to **2.5.10**

We store the user hierarchy information as is the below structure :

```
case class User(id : String , firstName : String, lastName : String,email : String)
case class UserSupervisors(id : String , userId : String, supervisorId : String)
```

Now one of our use case is :

**For a given user id , we need to display the user's information as well as information of all his subordiantes .**

Using play-slick the query written for the above use case is

```
  (for {
    userId <- TableQuery[UserSupervisors].filter(_.archive === false).filter(u => u.supervisorId === user.id).map(_.userId)
    user <- TableQuery[Users].filter(u => u.id === userId)
  } yield user) union TableQuery[Users].filter(_.id === user.id)
```

**This query worked for play 2.4.x and was used in production as well. Now after migrating the project to 2.5.10** , we encounter the following run time error

```
java.sql.SQLException: The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1078)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4120)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4052)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2503)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2664)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2815)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2155)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.execute(PreparedStatement.java:1379)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.proxy.PreparedStatementProxy.execute(PreparedStatementProxy.java:44)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.proxy.PreparedStatementJavassistProxy.execute(PreparedStatementJavassistProxy.java)
        at slick.jdbc.StatementInvoker.results(StatementInvoker.scala:39)
        at slick.jdbc.StatementInvoker.iteratorTo(StatementInvoker.scala:22)
        at slick.jdbc.Invoker$class.first(Invoker.scala:31)
        at slick.jdbc.StatementInvoker.first(StatementInvoker.scala:16)
        at slick.driver.JdbcActionComponent$QueryActionExtensionMethodsImpl$$anon$3.run(JdbcActionComponent.scala:228)
        at slick.driver.JdbcActionComponent$SimpleJdbcDriverAction.run(JdbcActionComponent.scala:32)
        at slick.driver.JdbcActionComponent$SimpleJdbcDriverAction.run(JdbcActionComponent.scala:29)
        at slick.backend.DatabaseComponent$DatabaseDef$$anon$2.liftedTree1$1(DatabaseComponent.scala:237)
        at slick.backend.DatabaseComponent$DatabaseDef$$anon$2.run(DatabaseComponent.scala:237)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

As per the play docs :

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/PlaySlick
https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/PlaySlick

Both version use slick 3.1.

The error thrown is a known error wrt mysql , but what we want to understand is why does the query work with play 2.4.x but not with play 2.5.x , when both use the same slick version

MySQL version used  by us : **5.7**

Do we need to change the slick query structure for unions , or did we miss any migration feature that needs to be applied while migrating an existing play app form 2.4.x to 2.5.x

Thanks in advance

Comment: try printing the query generated in both the versions to debug this further like this `query.statements.foreach(println)`

Comment: select x2.`firstName` as x5,x2.`id` as x9,x2.`email` as x16, x2.`lastName` as x19 
from `USER_SUPERVISOR` x24, `USER` x2 where (x24.`supervisorId` = 'e09808e4-fd95-42da-bdc0-915f1162f438') and (x2.`id` = x24.`userId`) 
union 
select `firstName` as x5, `id` as x9, `email` as x16,`lastName` as x19 from `USER` where `id` = 'e09808e4-fd95-42da-bdc0-915f1162f438'

Comment: Also it worked perfect when I ran it on mysql